# Error in extracting time based on a format from a file using Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

13:20:06.037

13:20:06.038

13:20:06.039

I want to read the timestamps from a file using python and compare the difference between adjacent values. Below is the code I used for this.

```
h, m, s = str(diff).split(':')

v,w = str(s).split('.')
```

I tried to split the diff in to hours,minutes and seconds using split(':'). In s, there is seconds and milliseconds value. When I try to run the second line of code, I get the error:" ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack".

Comment: What are you trying so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string to datetime with fractional seconds, on Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408494/string-to-datetime-with-fractional-seconds-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to convert string records from a file then You should try:

```
--put here Your code, that retrieves time records from file--
format = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
time_string = '09:54:11.001'
time = datetime.strptime(time_string, format)
```

This function does the job with displaying time, as You wanted to:

```
strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f", *put your time variable here*)
```

And this code snippet shows how to get a difference between two dates in Your format:

```
time1 = '09:54:11.001'
time2 = '10:32:43.837'
format = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
difference = datetime.strptime(time2, format) - datetime.strptime(time1, format)
```

You can read more about time functions in Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Regards.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added more complex explanation.

Comment: Good explanation , I understood it very well